# Why is Environment.NewLine showing up as square character?

Tags: newline, cultureinfo

I'm working with a .Net windows application. On my machine, a form displays Environment.NewLine correctly as a new line. However, on a tester's machine, the same Environment.NewLine is being displayed as a square character. On both of our machines, we have our regional settings temporarily set to French, for testing purposes.

How do I set up the tester's machine to display the Environment.Newline properly?

Answer (score 0):

First step - find out what `Environment.NewLine` actually *is* on the tester's machine. Perhaps it's somehow `\n` instead of `\r\n`, although I find it hard to imagine how...

Just print out `Environment.NewLine.Length` as a starting point.

Comment: In addition, convert each character to an integer value, so you can see what they are on the ASCII/Unicode table.